# Format placeholder in string.format to pick substring of an argument

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there a format string for the C# `string.Format` method that picks a substring from the corresponding argument? Like so:

```
var lang1 = "EN";
var lang2 = "FR";

var shortFormat = "Foo-{0:0-0}.pdf";
var longFormat = "Foo-{0:0-1}.pdf";

string.Format(shortFormat, lang1) // Foo-E.pdf
string.Format(shortFormat, lang2) // Foo-F.pdf
string.Format(longFormat, lang1) // Foo-EN.pdf
string.Format(longFormat, lang2) // Foo-FR.pdf
```

To anticipate a few comments: Yes, I know the `Substring` method. I have also read that string.Format is slower than a simple Substring. The example above is heavily simplified. Imagine that the string.Format statement resides in one place, while the `lang1`/`lang2` argument is an input from another place and the `shortFormat`/`longFormat` is defined in a resx file.

That is, in the place where the format is to be defined we don't know anything about the value being formatted (lang1/lang2 in the example) nor do we have any means to execute C# code. Hence we can't call any method such as `Substring` on the value. At the place where the formatting code runs, in turn, we take the format as a parameter, so we can't simply perform a `Substring` on the value because we don't know whether the format requires it or not (except if we inspect the format).

Answer (score 0):

No, the `string.Format` does not have this feature, which is better explained here: [Can maximum number of characters be defined in C# format strings like in C printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105386/can-maximum-number-of-characters-be-defined-in-c-sharp-format-strings-like-in-c)

If you don't want to use `Substring` I would create an extension class for `string` like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

```
namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string ShortFormat(this string str)
        {
            // manipulate and return str here
        }
        public static string LongFormat(this string str)
        {
            // manipulate and return str here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid of that. As for the suggestion with the extension methods - I think this still would not solve my issue, as I mentioned in my "anticipate" part: In the place where the format is defined (e.g. in a resx file), the value is not known. That's why it can't be accessed either for a `Substring` or for any extension methods on it.

Comment: Oh, ok. Pretty difficult then =/

Answer (score 0):

[XSLT formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp) can be an option: user gets ability to provide almost everything in configuration file and even execute custom c# code in your domain if it is required.

Please also consider that changes of format can be restricted to relatively small amount of actions: crop, pad or insert one or two things in some positions. Each one can be set as individual function and provided with own parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to provide custom formatting. You can either implement `IFormattable` on a custom type to control how that type is always formatted, or implement `IFormatProvider` to override how other types are formatted in specific cases.

In your case I would suggest creating a new type to encapsulate how your software deals with language codes;

```cs
public struct LanguageCode : IFormattable {
   public readonly string Code;
   public LanguageCode(string code) {
      Code = code;
   }

   public override string ToString()
      => this.ToString("L", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
   public string ToString(string format)
      => this.ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

   public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider){
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
         format = "L";
      if (provider == null)
         provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
      switch (format.ToUpperInvariant()){
         case "L": // Long
            return Code.ToString(provider);
         case "S": // Short
            return Code.SubString(0,1).ToString(provider);
         default:
            throw new FormatException($"The {format} format string is not supported.");
      }
   }

   public static implicit operator LanguageCode(string code)
      => new LanguageCode(code);
   public static implicit operator string(LanguageCode language)
      => language.Code;
}
```

Then from your example;

```
   var lang1 = (LanguageCode)"EN";
   LanguageCode lang2 = "FR";

   var shortFormat = "Foo-{0:S}.pdf";
   var longFormat = "Foo-{0:L}.pdf";
```