# C# Build a string evaluating another string as the template/rule/format to do it

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

I'm thinking about an application that builds some kind of usernames depending on the category where the user belongs. The problem starts when I try to generate this username from a rule contained in a table.

Example:

#### Data DataTable

```
| ID | Name  | City   | Level  | Rule |
|----|-------|--------|--------|------|
| 1  | John  | London |   A    |  1   |
| 2  | Chris | Paris  |   C    |  1   |
| 3  | Anna  | Madrid |   B    |  3   |
| 4  | Marie | Roma   |   C    |  2   |
```

#### Rules DataTable

```
| Rule | Format                      |
|------|-----------------------------|
|  1   | "Name + City"               |
|  2   | "Name[0] + City[0] + Level" |
|  3   | "Name[0] + \".\" + City"    |
```

And I would like to get as a final result:

```
| ID | Username   |
|----|------------|
| 1  | JonhLondon |
| 2  | ChrisParis |
| 3  | A.Madrid   |
| 4  | MRC        |
```

So I was thinking if there is a nice method that can build the username using the string contained in the rules table as the template to do it like:

```
string Name = dtData[i].Name;
string City = dtData[i].City;
string Level = dtData[i].Level;
string u = SomeGreatMethodToEvaluate(dtRules[dtData[i].Rule].Format);
dtFinal[i].Username = u;
```

Sorry if I didn't explain it good enough, but it's a tricky thing for me.

Comment: I think you've explained your question very well, the problem is I see no way to answer this without an essay - making this entirely too broad.

Comment: If you need templating, Razor is very effective https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/ , If you want to write your own templating syntax that is beyond the scope of an answer here, good luck. If the task is trivial just use a format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to leverage `String.Format` to do this.  You would store the format string in the database and pass in the parameters in a consistent way, e.g. Name, City, Level, Rule.  A pattern like `"Name + City"` becomes pretty easy, it just requires the format string `"{0}{1}"`.

`String.Format` doesn't support taking parts of `Strings` out of the box, but you can extend its functionality with an `IFormatProvider` and a custom class to wrap your strings.  There are good pointers in the related question: [Can maximum number of characters be defined in C# format strings like in C printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105386/can-maximum-number-of-characters-be-defined-in-c-sharp-format-strings-like-in-c).

Comment: I think I will try this in order to avoid install some external packages in the server, but I should take a look at how the patterns can be used. Anyway I will have to make my own class to wrap strings and analyze the rules before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/), which is a templating engine, could fit nicely here. With DotLiquid, your rules essentially become templates, which you then feed data into, producing desired result:

```
1. {{ name }}{{ city }}
2. {{ name | first | upcase }}{{ city | first | upcase }}{{ level }}
3. {{ name | first | upcase }}.{{ city }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using your own set of rules, you have to parse them yourself.
But when you use a standard set of rules, like [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for example, then you may find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194584/what-is-a-good-c-sharp-compiler-compiler-parser-generator) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5676/Spart-a-parser-generator-framework-C).